# How to terminate TIdTCPServer?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe8

I have a client that constantly tries to connect to `TIdTCPServer` like this:

```
if not Form1.tcpSender.Connected then
try
  sleep(2000);
  Form1.tcpSender.Connect;
except
   if Form1.tcpSender.IOHandler <> nil then
     Form1.tcpSender.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
end
```

And this works fine. Actually it works so fine that even when I close my server application it still reconnects.

But when I restart the server it throws an error saying:

> Could not bind socket. Address and port are already in use.

This is weird since I'm not using a separate thread for the server, so I assume that `TIdTCPServer` somehow remains active after the application is closed.

Can I somehow terminate it better?

Comment: Possibly, server application stays in processes.(?)

Comment: It's part of how "fine" it "works", I guess. Improper closing of a connection? Sockets left in [`TIME_WAIT`](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) state?

Comment: I would also guess that the server application is stuck in a process in the background, and hasn't actually terminated. Check the task manager.

Comment: @JerryDodge has the first part, your problem is almost certainly on the server side, not the client side.  Once you validate that he is correct you will need to dig into what is preventing your server process from exiting in a timely manner and then dealing with that issue.  Sometimes it is open connections on TIdTCPServer that aren't closing because they are stuck in a sub-optimal part of the state machine (running a large DB query, streaming GB of data, etc.).  Sometimes it is other long-running threads in your server app.

Comment: OnClose:
 Server.StopListening;
 Server.active:=false;

Assuming client is sending images to server and it's async operation is it possible
that when I hit ctrl+f2 in Delphi to terminate it's leaving server active? It's not visible in task manager. I just need to kill it somehow..